# moviepy textclip not rendered on centos7 or amazon linux but renders perfectly fine on mac

Tags: moviepy

Code to generate a simple mp4 movie with text, background and image

```
from moviepy.editor import *

image = ImageClip("res/pagan.png")
image = image.set_duration(5)
image = image.set_position((50, "center"))

backgroundImage = ImageClip("res/background.png")
backgroundImage = backgroundImage.set_duration(5)

fromText = TextClip("From: " , fontsize=70, color="white")
fromText = fromText.set_position((800, 320))
fromText = fromText.set_duration(5)

comp =  CompositeVideoClip([backgroundImage, image, fromText])

output = comp.set_duration(5)
output.write_videofile("tmp.mp4", audio_codec="aac", fps=24)
```

The movie renders without any errors on both macbook pro and centos7. However, the text is not rendered properly on the centos7 server or amazon linux.  It is just displayed as blurred out white lines. Has anyone faced a similar issue before? I have lodged this is a [bug](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1647) on moviepy as well but thought of posting here to see if anyone has faced similar issues in the past.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the Imagemagick version between the two environments. Looks like I needed ImageMagick 7.1.0. Refer to https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1647 for details on how I narrowed this down.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the Imagemagick version between the two environments. Looks like I needed ImageMagick 7.1.0. Refer to [github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1647](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1647) for details on how I narrowed this down.